# Capture UAC Username

Tags: uac

Is there any way to capture the username that someone enters at a UAC prompt? I have a script that requires admin rights to run, that other people will also be running on other systems. I’d like to capture the username they enter (I don’t care about the password) and the date/time they enter it, to track usage. Is this possible? These would mostly be Windows domain accounts, but some local accounts too.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I just thought of this and it seems to work. I can just use `whoami` and send the name to a file or whatever.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).